# Как избежать сложности O(N*M)?

Tags: java, алгоритм, сложность

Есть список `List<User> users` объектов следующего класса:

```
public class User {
    Set<String> groups;
}
```

И имеется список `Set<String> targetGroups`.

Необходимо найти всех пользователей, у которых есть группа, которая находится в множестве `targetGroups`. Перебор в лоб даёт сложность `O(N * M)` *(количество пользователей * количество групп)*:

```
users.stream()
    .filter(user -> !user.getGroups().isEmpty())
    .filter(user -> user.getGroups().stream().anyMatch(targetGroups::contains))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());;
```

В задании предлагается выполнить алгоритм со сложностью `O(N)`. Я не вижу, как это может быть возможным.

Возможно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 3):

Пусть

- `N` кол-во пользователей
- `K` кол-во групп у пользователя
- `M` кол-во элементов в `targetGroups`

Тогда твой поиск - это `O(N*K)`, потому что операция `Set.contains` считается как `O(1)`

Если `K << M` (`K` сильно меньше чем `M`), то твой алгоритм нормальный.

Если `K >> M`, то стоит поменять на

```
.filter(user -> targetGroups.stream().anyMatch(user.getGroups()::contains))
```

Если неизвестно заранее, то максимум, что тут можно выжать

```
.filter(user -> {
  if (targetGroups.size() <= user.getGroups().size()) {
    return targetGroups.stream().anyMatch(user.getGroups()::contains);
  } else {
    return user.getGroups().stream().anyMatch(targetGroups::contains);
  }
})
```

---

> В задании предлагается выполнить алгоритм со сложностью O(N).

Вероятно, в задании или `K` или `M` предполагаются или константными или пренебрежимо малыми по сравнению с `N`. В таком случае, твой алгоритм будет `O(N)`

Answer (score 2):

Для данного условия задачи, когда группы - это некие множества строк `Set<String>`, сложность можно несколько уменьшить, как описано [в ответе Александра Павлова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1377572/386633).

Дополнительная оптимизация возможна, если сеты групп заранее представлены в виде неких битовых множеств `BitSet`/или чисел `BigInteger`, где каждой группе соответствует свой бит.  Тогда можно просто использовать [`BitSet::intersects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#intersects-java.util.BitSet-) или же побитовую операцию AND и сравнение с 0 для `BigInteger`.

```java
public class User {
    BitSet groups;
}
// ...
BitSet targetGroups;

List<User> targeted = users
    .stream()
    .filter(u -> u.getGroups().intersects(targetGroups))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Аналогично для `BigInteger`:

```java
public class User {
    BigInteger groups;
}
// ...
BigInteger targetGroups;

List<User> targeted = users
    .stream()
    .filter(u -> u.getGroups().and(targetGroups).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Тут нужно не забывать, что `BitSet.intersects()` и `BigInteger.and()` работают не за O(1) и содержат внутри цикл. Там, конечно, обрабатываются целиком слова, а не отдельные биты, но при высокой мощности множества групп это будет O(N/64) = O(N)

Comment: Хороший вариант, можно воспользоваться, но тут из-за преобразование строк в биты как раз и получится O(N*M). Но потом конечно сравнение будет быстрое.